# Text-align right not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a table that is being generated where one of the columns needs its text to be aligned right. So right it looks something like this:

```
<td class="generatedClass" id="generatedId" style="width:20px; text-align:right;">
   <label id="generatedRowId"> some text here </label>
</td>
```

It works in IE9 and IE8, but for some reason not IE7. Anyone have an idea as to why this might not be working? To note, the inline styles are being created as json objects. I don't like having inline styles, but it wasn't my call.

Comment: Maybe <label> has display:block. Can you post the css related to that?

Comment: Did you attempt set style (width and text-align) on label?

Comment: The label has only an auto generated ID which is populated by where it is currently in the array of information being pushed out to this table. I also did attempt to put in on the label before coming here, thinking that would be the better solution, but  it seems for some reason it doesn't want to take the styles there either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it should work. Probably, IE7 is not updating the DOM after these inline styles are being applied.

I recommend opening the page in IE10 and then going to IE7 Page mode. You should then be able to inspect the styles on your element and find out if they're being applied, overridden, etc.

Comment: This was a fantastic idea, though the element is still getting text-align: right; . HOWEVER, while inspecting it, I noticed that the width is what is causing the issue in the <td>. If I adjust the width, it increases the size of the cell but in IE 7 aligns it "more right". I think the best approach from here would be getting static IDs going for each column and then using different style sheets to target this issue.

Comment: Please, add classes, not IDs. You can't duplicate IDs throughout the elements on your page.

Comment: IE7 is naturally going to interpret your CSS a bit differently than modern browsers. If you need your table to look just a certain way, then setting classes for each of the table rows might be your best option, though I have never had to.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like width property of your inline style casing problem in IE7. Try to eliminate to apply with in inline style.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="400">
<tr>
<td class="generatedClass" id="generatedId" style="text-align:right;">
   <label id="generatedRowId"> some text here </label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```